# yii2 i18n not working with buttons

Tags: yii2, internationalization

I am trying to set i18n into my website. I did all configurations like following:
common/config/main.php

```
'language' => 'uz-UZ',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
// ...
'components' => [
//...
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                //'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
//...
```

Directories:

```
- common
   -messages
      -en-EN
         app.php
      -ru-RU
         app.php
```

ru-RU/app.php file:

```
return [
    'Bosh sahifa' => 'Домашная страница'
];
```

And when I put `\Yii::$app->language = 'ru-RU'` into layouts/main.php file, it's working. But when I am using buttons to change language, i18n is not working.
code for buttons in layouts/main.php:

```
<div>
   <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/lang', 'lang' => 'uz']) ?>">uz</a>
   <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/lang', 'lang' => 'ru']) ?>">ru</a>
   <a href="<?= Url::to(['site/lang', 'lang' => 'en']) ?>">en</a>
</div>
```

site/lang:

```
public function actionLang($lang)
{
    switch ($lang) {
        case "en":
            \Yii::$app->language = "en-EN";
            break;
        case "ru":
            \Yii::$app->language = "ru-RU";
            break;
        case "uz":
            \Yii::$app->language = "uz-UZ";
            break;
        default:
            \Yii::$app->language = "uz-UZ";
    }
    $this->goBack();
}
```

Please, help!

Comment: [Will help](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/i18n-selecting-application-language/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895120/change-language-in-yii2)

Comment: I've changed it as given in a page that you linked. Now It is working for only layout/main.php, not for other pages such as index.php or view.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not storing the language settings (for given client) anywhere. In fact the language is changed only when `actionLang()` is opened, but it won't work, because you are immediately redirecting to the previous page using `$this->goBack()` (where no $lang parameter is passed).

I suggest you to read this documentation about language detection:
[Yii2 Cookbook - Selecting application language](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md)

Briefly: In [Support selecting language manually](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md#support-selecting-language-manually) section you see that it's possible to store language settings in user cookies or database. And on app bootstrap you fetch the language preferences, and set it into application.

Open application config and add the following code to your `boostrap` section:

```
return [
    'bootstrap' => [
        [
            'class' => 'app\components\LanguageSelector',
            'supportedLanguages' => ['en_US', 'ru_RU'],
        ],
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Then create the `LanguageSelector` class and write something like:
namespace app\components;

```
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

class LanguageSelector implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public $supportedLanguages = [];

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        $preferredLanguage = isset($app->request->cookies['language']) ? (string)$app->request->cookies['language'] : null;

        if (empty($preferredLanguage)) {
            $preferredLanguage = $app->request->getPreferredLanguage($this->supportedLanguages);
        }

        $app->language = $preferredLanguage;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Also you can look up to [yii2-localeurls](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls) extension, which can make it easier to manage languages in you application.
All you have to do is to add the extension component to your config file, and you can easily change your application language using this kind of links:

```
<?= $url = Url::to(['demo/action', 'language' => 'fr']) ?>
<?= Html::a('Click', ['demo/action', 'language' => 'fr']) ?>
```

Notice that it will display language in URL like `/fr/demo/action`, which is very useful for SEO

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me